# Python method summary mute repr

Tags: python

How to make the repr is not called when displaying the method description, or how to reduce its size for such a case.

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = {i:i for i in range(100)}
>>> u = collections.UserDict({i:i for i in range(100)})
>>> repr(d)
'{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, .... # Shows the full contents of the dictionary - this is correct
>>> repr(u)
'{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, .... # Shows the full contents of the dictionary - this is correct
>>> d.pop
<built-in method pop of dict object at 0x7f0233844400>  # Not call __repr__ 
>>> u.pop
<bound method MutableMapping.pop of {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, ....}>  # Call __repr__, If the __repr__ is large, it is very inconvenient
```

Comment: The function `repr()` is primarily of use when debugging and, yes, sometimes its output can be inconveniently long. Your options are (1) don't call it and instead write a function to present abbreviated output and call that, or (2) write a subclass of `UserDict` and provide a `__repr__()` magic method that does what you want.

Comment: I want to have the correct __repr__() in my class, but at the same time the summary of the method was shown short as in the class dict in my sample

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your question to  *include the code* of your  `__repr__()`  method because you did not make it at all clear that you had provided one. But be aware that there can only be one implementation of `repr()`. To have it do different things in different circumstances it would have to be coded to examine the call stack.

Comment: I am satisfied with the behavior of the original `__repr__()`, but the problem is that `__repr__` is used in both cases, and in the second case it is not needed.
I also thought that the solution was to check the call stack, but I wanted to find a more beautiful solution.

Comment: But the one `repr()` calls the other. There isn't any other reasonable way to implement a generic function that reports on a complex data structure that may contain another data structure. It has to rely on the `repr()` of the contained data structure.